# Telnet to machine not on the same subnet

Tags: linux, windows, networking, telnet, putty

I have a network of windows machines on one subnet (192.xx.xx) and a network of Linux machines on another (172.xx.xx). I have a Linux gateway machine that is able to see both the windows and Linux machines.

I'm trying to telnet into one of the Linux machines, however I do not have telnet installed on any of the Linux machines; just putty on the windows.

Is there a way to telnet to one of the Linux machines on the Windows? The windows machines can't see the Linux machines other than the gateway. But the windows can access the gateway.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please move your question to [su] or [sf] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

This seems more like a question for https://serverfault.com/

What you need is the following:

- enable IP forwarding on the Linux gateway machine (make sure iptables also allows the forwarded traffic)
- systems on each side of the gateway must have the linux gateway's IP in their subnet as default gateway, or at least as gateway in a static route to the subnet on the other side

Also, you should avoid telnet if you can and use SSH if you can.